# simple concatenation in intelliJ

Tags: string, scala, intellij-idea, string-concatenation

I am trying to reach to this service using the following link within intelliJ;
however iam getting an "Illegal character in scheme name at index..." where the date starts. 'single quotes do not work, and '+' concatenation does not work either. Any idea on how to solve this?

```
serviceCall("""http://example.com/books/report?name=abc&param=env=deck&time="13 Apr 2010"&acct=N&id=wre23""")
```

Comment: Have you tried the solutions from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters ?

Comment: @Kolmar not tried but will do thanks